# bwapp IDOR (change secret)

Tags: javascript, php, security, web-applications, penetration-testing

I'm pentesting on buggy web app(bWAPP). I am not finding solutions on the web for the problem IDOR(Change secret) **In medium security level**. So I wondered if someone here can help me with it. Aparently I just have to decode a token to then change its username to another account an then enconde it again, but don't seem like it is a jason web token. Can someone guess what it is and help me out decode it? If you have a link to the solution **ON MEDIUM SECURITY LEVEL** it will also be welcome. Thank you.

Here is the HTTP request I have to change using a proxy (I'm currently using Burp Suite).

```
POST /bwapp/insecure_direct_object_ref_1.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 74
Origin: http://localhost
Connection: close
Referer: http://localhost/bwapp/insecure_direct_object_ref_1.php
Cookie: security_level=1; PHPSESSID=a8dslb3cr3r36l4t7g0h032gj5
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

secret=sdfsdf&token=b096f2c01e7b8c3ce54791366d40d72ac4c15564&action=change
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to change the sessionid in cookie too. Web server always determine a client by its sessionid. So have a try.